# IOS: How to get specific changed child from list in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have List of objects in firebase DB. how to get specific child who changed in the list?
Do I have made connection with every child?

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes you have to do that. If you e.g. have users in there, you'll end up with something like this:

```
{
  users: {
    "user-0": {
      "firstName": "Max",
      "lastName": "Powers"
    },
    "user-1": {
      "firstName": "Maxime",
      "lastName": "Powers"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, from your apps perspective, the user is signed in and therefore the app knows the user-id. With this information you can subscribe to changes on the whole user.

If you go one step further and nest e.g. rides below each user, as a mobility app will do, you end up with a JSON like this:

```
{
  users: {
    "user-0": {
      "rides": {
        "ride-0": {
          "updated_at": ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When in this mobility app a user creates a ride, the app will will receive a ride-id from the backend which it can use to subscribe to the related ride in firebase. The path would be e.g. `users/<user-id>/rides/<ride-id>`. The app will then get updates each time this ride is updted in the realtime database.

In the end each user has multiple subscriptions. We do it for a couple of years this way and it works quite well